# IdentityServer3 does not connect to ADFS through UseWsFederationAuthentication

Tags: identityserver3

I'm using IdentityServer3 and I'm trying to integrate it with ADFS through UseWsFederationAuthentication but does not seem to be working. It's working without IdentityServer it redirects to the login page and it completes without any problem. But when I do it through IdentityServer there is no response. As I check the fiddler logs, I can see it downloads the metadata but no action after that.
What could be the reason?

Fiddler Trace:

[image: Fiddler Trace:]

IdentityServer3 Login

[image: IdentityServer3 Login]

IdentityServer OWIN Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var idsrvManager = new IdentityServerManager();
        var tenants = idsrvManager.GetTenants();
        foreach (var tenant in tenants)
        {
            app.Map(string.Format("/identity/{0}", tenant.ShortName), ids =>
             {
                 ids.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
                 {
                     SiteName = string.Format("Identity Server for {0}", tenant.Name),
                     IssuerUri = string.Format(Templates.Issuer, tenant.ShortName),
                     SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
                     Factory = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerServiceFactory
                     {
                         UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(new InMemoryUserService(Users.Get())),
                         ClientStore = new Registration<IClientStore>(new InMemoryClientStore(Clients.Get(tenant.ShortName))),
                         ScopeStore = new Registration<IScopeStore>(new InMemoryScopeStore(Scopes.Get()))
                     },
                     AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions
                     {
                         EnableSignOutPrompt = false,

                         IdentityProviders = delegate (IAppBuilder appBuilder, string sAsType)
                         {
                             var hasDefaultIdp = false;
                             var authType = string.Empty;
                             foreach (var idp in tenant.IdentityProviders)
                             {
                                 authType = !hasDefaultIdp && idp.IsDefault ? Defaults.Idp : idp.IdentityProviderType.Name;
                                 hasDefaultIdp = !hasDefaultIdp && idp.IsDefault;
                                 if (idp.IdentityProviderType.Name == IdPConstants.ActiveDirectory)
                                 {
                                     appBuilder.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
                                     {
                                         Wtrealm = idp.Wtrealm,
                                         MetadataAddress = idp.MetadataAddress,
                                         AuthenticationType = authType,
                                         Caption = string.Format(Templates.Caption, IdPConstants.ActiveDirectory),
                                         SignInAsAuthenticationType = sAsType,
                                         BackchannelCertificateValidator = null,
                                         Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                                         {
                                             RedirectToIdentityProvider = (n) =>
                                             {
                                                 return Task.FromResult(0);
                                             }
                                         }
                                     });
                                 }
```

MVC Application OWIN Startup

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = Defaults.MVCAppName,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "openid",
            BackchannelCertificateValidator = null,
            ConfigurationManager = new TenantOpenIdConfigurationManager(new List<string>() { "Contoso" }),
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = (n) =>
                {
                    n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = string.Format(Templates.WebApp, "Contoso"); // This is a hardcoded value should be taken at runtime.
                    n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = string.Format(Templates.ArcValues, Defaults.Idp); ;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Logs:

2017-09-21 17:51:45.177 +05:30 [Information] identity provider requested, redirecting to: "default"
2017-09-21 17:51:45.181 +05:30 [Information] External login requested for provider: "default"
2017-09-21 17:51:45.186 +05:30 [Information] Triggering challenge for external identity provider
2017-09-21 17:51:45.187 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1867241Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Action', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Action returned 'System.Web.Http.Results.UnauthorizedResult'', Operation=ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync
2017-09-21 17:51:45.189 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1887241Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Action', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=ApiControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
2017-09-21 17:51:45.190 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1897241Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Action filter for 'Login(String signin)'', Operation=NoCacheAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
2017-09-21 17:51:45.191 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1907241Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=NoCacheAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
2017-09-21 17:51:45.193 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1917241Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Action filter for 'Login(String signin)'', Operation=SecurityHeadersAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
2017-09-21 17:51:45.194 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1937241Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Filters', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=SecurityHeadersAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
2017-09-21 17:51:45.196 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1947241Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=AuthenticationController.ExecuteAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
2017-09-21 17:51:45.197 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1967241Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.MessageHandlers', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.SendAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
2017-09-21 17:51:45.198 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1977241Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.MessageHandlers', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=DependencyScopeHandler.SendAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
2017-09-21 17:51:45.199 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1987241Z] Sending response, Status=401 (Unauthorized), Method=GET, Url=<>?signin=5c391119163f5581602559efabbb3443, Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Message='Content-type='none', content-length=unknown'
2017-09-21 17:51:45.200 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.1997241Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=AuthenticationController.Dispose
2017-09-21 17:51:45.201 +05:30 [Debug] [2017-09-21T12:21:45.2007241Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.Controllers', Id=80000077-0000-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb, Operation=AuthenticationController.Dispose

Comment: Could someone help me please?

Comment: You're going to need to include some of your code (OWIN Startup for both OIDC & WS-Fed). Also, maybe format those logs :p

Comment: @ScottBrady I've added the OWIN startup code.

Comment: Could someone answer my question please?